# How to find an overloaded method that matches a certain signature?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to find a constructor of an arbitrary class that matches given var-args parameters. Unfortunately I'm making very little progress as I'm having a hard time understanding Scala's reflection API. After retrieving a list of all available constructors I fail to identify one that matches the available arguments.

```
private lazy val `class` = mirror.staticClass( "myPackage.myClass" )

protected def reflect( arguments: Any* ): T =
{
    val constructor = `class`
        .toType
        .members
        .collect{ case method: MethodSymbol if method.isConstructor => method }
        .collectFirst[MethodSymbol]{ case _ => null  } // ???
        .getOrElse( throw new RuntimeException( "No valid constructor given" ) )

    mirror
        .reflectClass( `class` )
        .reflectConstructor( constructor )
        .apply( arguments: _* )
        .asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cover it on my blog post about [scala reflection, part 1](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html). A `MethodSymbol` has a `typeSignature`, from which we can evaluate things. For example, from the post, the method below will get you all `Int`-returning methods for an object:

```
def intMethods[T : TypeTag](v: T) = {
  val IntType = typeOf[Int]
  val vType   = typeOf[T]
  val methods = vType.members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if !m.isPrivate => m -> m.typeSignatureIn(vType)
  }
  methods collect {
    case (m, mt @ NullaryMethodType(IntType))          => m -> mt
    case (m, mt @ MethodType(_, IntType))              => m -> mt
    case (m, mt @ PolyType(_, MethodType(_, IntType))) => m -> mt
  }
}
```